# EmguCV/Open CV - Is there a way to search for a template sub- mage multiple times?

Tags: c#, image, opencv, emgucv

I'm using the code used off the tutorial on Emgu's website with the following code :

```
 using (Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
        {
            double[] minValues, maxValues;
            Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
            result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
            // You can try different values of the threshold. I guess somewhere between 0.75 and 0.95 would be good.
            if (maxValues[0] > 0.6)
            {
                // This is a match. Do something with it, for example draw a rectangle around it.
                Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], template.Size);
                imageToShow.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
            }
        }
```

It works great to identify a single sub-image inside of another image. But I was wondering how you would go about adapting this code to identify multiple instances.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just scan the 'result' image by yourself rather than using MinMax method, to find the pixels that satisfy your condition (e.g. val > 0.6).

Or, after find the max value with MinMax, fill the 'maxLocation' pixel with 0 in 'result' and run MinMax again. Do this as many as you want. But I guess the first method runs faster because it only needs one scan.